# My client wont connect to its server

Tags: java, server, client

I have made `Client.java` and `Server.java`. Here they are below.

`Client`

```
public class Client
{

ClientConnection cc;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Client();
}
public Client()
{
    try
    {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost",4444);
        cc = new ClientConnection(s,this);
        cc.start();

        listenForInput();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void listenForInput(){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        while(!console.hasNextLine()){
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String input = console.nextLine();
        cc.sendStringToServer(input);
    }
}
}
```

`Server`

```
public class Server
{
    ServerSocket ss;
    ArrayList<ServerConnection> connections = new ArrayList<ServerConnection>();
    boolean shouldRun = true;
    ServerWindow serverWindow;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Server();
}
public Server(){
    try
    {
        serverWindow= new ServerWindow();
        serverWindow.setVisible(true);
        ss = new ServerSocket(4444);
        serverWindow.serverLog("Server starting");
        while(shouldRun){

            Socket s = ss.accept();
            ServerConnection sc = new ServerConnection(s,this);
            sc.start();
            connections.add(sc);
            serverWindow.serverLog("A client connected from " + sc.getIP());
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public ServerWindow getServerWindow(){
    return serverWindow;
}
}
```

When i run `Client.java` and `Server.java` they connect fine and carry out their tasks as expected. But when I am in a new class and i create a client object and a server object, the client doesnt work properly.

```
public class tester
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Server server = new Server();
    Client client = new Client();


    client.cc.sendStringToServer("From tester");

}

}
```

The `server` works fine, it creates the window as expected but the `client` object doesnt work. My `server` object will not recognize a connection like it does when it normally works and my `client`'s message will not go through. What am I missing? Does it have to do with using `localhost` as the ip?

Comment: What is ServerConnection and ClientConnection? Give us some more detail, we can not read your thoughts.

Comment: ServerConnection and ClientConnection are threads for each person who connects. ClientConnection is a client side thread that handles sending and receiving. ServerConnection is a thread for each person that connects. I don't see how those are relevant to the question. For example if I put a print statement in the `client` constructor, I don't get a print to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you block the main thread by calling

```
listenForInput();
```

in your Client. Create a new Thread that calls the input listener and you will be fine.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        listenForInput();
    }
}).start();
```

**Edit:** The same problem is in the Server class. There is an infinite loop, that blocks the Server constructor from finishing. Also add this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while(shouldRun) {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
}).start();
```

**Note:** You do not need to sleep the thread when waiting for input. Just write some empty brackets or a semicolon.

```
while (!console.hasNextLine()) ;
```

Comment: I understand your response but that does not solve the problem I have. Its almost as if `Client client = new Client(); ` doesn't actually call the `Client` constructor and then in turn never connects to a server. For example, if i place `System.out.println("TEST");` in the constructor of the `Server` object, "TEST" gets printed to the console when i declare a new Server object as expected. If i put that same command in the `Client` constructor i get no such message to the console when making a Client object.

Comment: Same problem in the Server class, see Edit.

Comment: Does a constructor have to fully complete for it to work? Also if i use your fix for the server file it doesnt work because there is this line - `ServerConnection sc = new ServerConnection(s,this);` and it identifies `this` as the thread and not the server.

Comment: In the `main` method you first call the server and afterwards the client. The code line with the client will not be executed, because the server line does not finish. Declare a global variable `Server that = this;` and use `that` instead of `this` in the thread.